How to give numbers by order to column in ArcGIS Pro through FieldCalculator and Python
How to give numbers by order to column in ArcGIS Pro through FieldCalculator and Python?
Sequence doesn't work as I need. I sorted X_North and need to give a numbering (from 1 to 296) to new column. I am not Python profs and following code doesn't work. Any tips?


This is a duplicate Question. Your code block doesn't do anything except add a short delay before returning None. You need to define a function that increments and returns a global variable.

Thank you for answer! Can you check picture above in a question part. I just add. How to modify code that all numbers will be written in a column not only 296? It was long time ago I used Python. Thank you in advance!

Check out the Accumulative and sequential calculations section of Calculate Field Python examples - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation.  Also, Esri now provides a Sequential Number helper in Calculate Field.

Ok. But Sequential Number doesnt work as i need. It haves ObjectId numbers. And i need other order as i sorted.

Please always provide code as formatted text rather than only in pictures.

Sort (Data Management - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation can be used to align data and ObjectIDs before running Sequential Number.  If you are open to using cursors in ArcPy, it opens the doors to other options.
